# Soma de data javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Na função adicionar e gerado através de um for a quantidade de parcelas que ira ter, preciso que gere uma data de vencimento a cada vez que existir parcela.

```
function adicionar(){
      ParcelaVencimento=$("#ParcelaVencimento").val();   
      ParcelaValor=$("#ParcelaValor").val();
      QtdParcela=$("#QtdParcela").val();

      for ($i = 0; $i < QtdParcela; $i++){

            subtotal[cont]=(ParcelaValor*1);
            total = total + subtotal[cont];
            var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha'+cont+'">    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="apagar('+cont+');"> X </button></td>      <td> <input type="hidden" name="cont[]" value="'+cont+'">'+cont+'</td>  <td> <input type="date" name="ParcelaVencimento[]" value="'+ParcelaVencimento+'"></td> <td> <input type="number" name="ParcelaValor[]" value="'+ParcelaValor+'"></td> <td> <input type="number" name="QtdParcela[]" value="'+QtdParcela+'"></td> </tr>'

            cont++;
```

Comment: PHP ou Javascript?

Comment: _"preciso que gere uma data de vencimento"_, e o que exatamente você quer fazer? Somar o que ao que?

Comment: @GiovanniNunes Em Javascript.

Comment: @GuilhermeConstamilam Irei adicionar uma data através de um input _ParcelaVencimento_ e o número de parcelas através de _QtdParcelas_ para cada parcela quero um mês diferente, ou seja, a QtdParcelas é a quantidade de mês, preciso somar na ParcelaVencimento para cada parcela.

Answer (score 1):

Há duas abordagens para este problema, no primeiro você considera que há um intervalo exato de 30 dias para a data de vencimento de cada parcela:

```
let dia = 23;
let mes = 4-1; // janeiro = 0
let ano = 2018;
let parcelas = 6;

for (let i=0; i<parcelas; i++){
    dataVencimento = new Date(ano, mes, dia + 30*i);
    dataComoString = dataVencimento.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log(dataComoString);
}
```

O que gerará as datas de vencimento: 23/04/2018, 23/05/2018, 22/06/2018, 22/07/2018, 21/08/2018 e 20/09/2018; Mas visto que não são todos os meses que possuem exatamente 30 dias você terá um deslocamento da data de vencimento.

A outra alternativa é considerar o cálculo da data utilizando o mês ao invés do dia, algo assim (alterei data e número de parcelas de propósito):

```
let dia = 30;
let mes = 4-1; // janeiro = 0
let ano = 2018;   
let parcelas = 12;

for (let i=0; i<parcelas; i++){
    dataVencimento = new Date(ano, mes + i, dia);
    dataComoString = dataVencimento.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log(dataComoString);
}
```

Que produzirá as datas de vencimento 30/04/2018, 30/05/2018, 30/06/2018, 30/07/2018, 30/08/2018, 30/09/2018, 30/10/2018, 30/11/2018, 30/12/2018, 30/01/2019, 02/03/2019 e 30/03/2019; Neste caso com datas mais próximos àquilo que as pessoas normalmente esperam.

Comment: No meu retorno apareceu `Mon Aug 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)` como colocar com a data normal? dd/mm/aaaa

Comment: Você está usando o método `.toLocaleDateString()` para converter o objeto em uma *string*? Caso contrário ele sempre aparecerá assim, no formato padrão de data.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei adaptar as variáveis dia/mês/ano e estou com o seguinte problema, o dia diminui o valor do i, o que ficou errado?

```
  for (let i=0; i<QtdParcela; i++){
        var Vencimento = ParcelaVencimento.split("/");
        var DataVencimento = Vencimento[2]+"-"+Vencimento[1]+"-"+Vencimento[0];
        var myDate = new Date(DataVencimento);
        var ano = myDate.getFullYear();
        var dia = myDate.getDate(); if(dia<10){dia='0'+dia};
        var mes = (myDate.getMonth()+1); if(mes<10){mes='0'+mes} 

        ParcelaVencimento = new Date(ano, mes + i, dia);
        ParcelaVencimento =  (dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]